# Intended way to run commands installed as dependencies

Tags: npm, virtualenv, npm-install

I'm working on a Django project using [Django Pipline](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline) to process CSS and JavaScript files when deploying the static files of the application. I would like to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to compile JSX source to JavaScript in that process. For this I will need to write a pipeline plugin which calls `babel` and passes it the JSX file.

To install Babel and its dependencies, I've set up a minimal `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": [
        "babel-cli@6.11.4",
        "babel-preset-react@6.11.1"
    ]
}
```

When I run `npm install` it will install all the necessary dependencies into `node_modules`.

This all works fine but there is one part which eludes me. I have not found a straightforward way to run the `babel` binary. `npm` installs those binaries under `node_modules/.bin`, which is also returned by `npm bin`:

```
$ find node_modules -name babel
node_modules/.bin/babel
node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel

$ npm bin
[...]/node_modules/.bin
```

What is the intended way to then e.g. run the `babel` binary?

Should I put that directory on my `$PATH`? Is there a script akin to the `activate` script from [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)? Should I hard-code the path in my project instead?

I'm sure the authors of npm have thought of that use case. Otherwise projects like Babel would live in a gray area of intended usages of npm.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `npm` scripts, the binaries in `node_modules/.bin` will get added to your `PATH`. So, you could create a, say, `"build"` script like so:

```json
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": [
        "babel-cli@6.11.4",
        "babel-preset-react@6.11.1"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build": "babel script.js"
    }
}
```

And then do `npm run build` to execute the script.